# How to prompt user to save the generated file?

Tags: web-applications

My programme generated a file when the user clicks a button. I created the file generation part in a method builder. Now I am wondering, how to prompt user to save the file to his local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the code where you generate the file would help. Try setting this content type.

```
 response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
```

"attachment;filename=yourfilename.txt");

I've also seen:

```
 response.setContentType("application/force-download");
```

[Source](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-download-file-from-website-java-jsp/)